# Cannot reach Microsoft.com sites from chrome or ping, but can from IE

Tags: http

What do I do so I can reach Microsoft.com from Chrome?

I'm having a problem: When I try to reach any other website, its ok. 
When I try any MS website it fails.

When I go through IE - it succeeds. Tried many times both ways, fails consistently via chrome, succeeds consistently via IE

---

Details:

Chrome gives me: Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)

Looking up on stackoverflow someone obviously had a similar problem with Facebook.com but got the thread closed ("too broad question!") https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11616375/

---

I ping microsoft.com and get timed out.

Tracert gives me this:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\pashute>tracert microsoft.com

Tracing route to microsoft.com [64.4.11.37] over a maximum of 30 hops:

1     5 ms     3 ms     3 ms  DSL6740U.Home [10.0.0.138]
2    22 ms    27 ms    34 ms  bzq-179-37-1.static.bezeqint.net [212.179.37.1]
3     *       22 ms    21 ms  bzq-218-103-210.red.bezeqint.net [81.218.103.210]
4    23 ms    22 ms    22 ms  bzq-179-75-198.static.bezeqint.net [212.179.75.198]
5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
6    80 ms    81 ms    81 ms  bzq-179-124-122.static.bezeqint.net [212.179.124.122]
7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
8     *        *        *     Request timed out.

etc etc. 

Trace complete.
```

Comment: DID HELP: Working from a different router. But didn't understand the long jaro-speak by other users. Need a step-by-explanation.

Comment: NOTE: The problem started after installing Checkpoint Endpoint Security. I removed it. And now finally get Internet up on wireless connection. Was constantly stalled beforehand. The problem went away at work, but at home stays...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear all Chrome browsing history!!!

Problem solved!
[*Thanks Elnora Stewart!!*]

---

First I only cleared history and chache "from beginning of time". 
- Didn't help.

Then cleared everything. 
- I can open Microsoft!!

Found [here at Yahoo answers](http://ph.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110707035508AAijObG)!

Content from Yahoo Answers:

> Clear your web history and try again browsing Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why chrome cannot reach but  Microsoft blocks icmp protocol because of Dos attacks hence you cannot ping because ping uses icmp protocol.

Source:[click here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001054.htm)

Comment: 1) OK that explains the ping!!

Still need to understand the rest. Thanks user1180619!!